# Is going to dargahs(Shrine over a sacred grave) allowed in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk

Is going to [dargah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dargah) a good practice, if not why? why do so many people in india go to dargahs?

Answer with full explanation please.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. To learn more about this site and the stack exchange model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and visit our [help].

Comment: Please note that the link I added to your post already gives a lot of evidences why this could be considered as shirk.

Comment: Some relevant posts: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28618/so-many-variations-of-islam-and-which-to-follow http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7651/does-magic-exist-in-reality/7656#7656

Comment: @Medi1Saif, How possibly could going to dargah is considered as shirk, don't add your opinion in shariyath?

Comment: @Ali786 I'm quoting Wikipedia not my opinion! And shari'a is crystal clear about shirk it doesn't need my opinion!

Comment: @Medi1Saif, Wikipedia isn't an authentic source to consider, pls don't take negatively..

Comment: Please see these http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2016/02/20/13096/ and http://www.questionsonislam.com/question/what-does-islam-say-about-visiting-graves-what-are-appropriate-manners-visiting-graves-isla

Answer (score 1):

I will try to be short, and it might seem one sided answer, but i am expressing what i believe is right.

**Building dargah/shrines is a separate matter, doing shirk is separate matter.**

Now, there's a whole debate and books written on building shrines and its status, but **it is clear that this is not islam's pure practice, there were no shrines built for sahaba/tabaeen/taba-tabaennn or people of good times (قرون اولٰی)**, in fact there are clear ahadees forbidden building any kind of building on graves.

Following are a few ahadees supporting this.

> Umm Salamah and Umm Habeebah (may Allaah be pleased with them) told
>   the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)
>   about a church that they had seen in the land of Abyssinia, and the
>   images that were in it. He (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)
>   said: “**When a righteous man died among them, they would build a place
>   of worship over his grave and put those images in it. They are the
>   most evil of mankind before Allaah.**” (Al-Bukhaari, 427; Muslim, 528)
>
> In Saheeh Muslim (532) Jundub ibn ‘Abd-Allaah (may
>   Allaah be pleased with him) said: “I heard the Messenger of Allaah
>   (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) say: ‘I stand acquitted
>   before Allah that I took anyone of you as a close friend (khaleel),
>   for Allah has taken me as His close friend, as He took Ibraaheem as
>   His close friend. Had I taken any one of my ummah as a close friend, I
>   would have taken Abu Bakr as a close friend. **Those who came before you
>   used to take the graves of their Prophets and righteous men as places
>   of worship, but you must not take graves as places of worship; I
>   forbid you to do that.**’”
>
> Sahih Muslim Number 1080: Abu Huraira reported: **The Messenger of Allah
>   (may peace be upon him) said: Let Allah destroy the Jews for they have
>   taken the graves of their apostles as places of worship**.
>
> Sahih Muslim Chapter 200: IT IS FORBIDDEN TO PLASTER THE GRAVE OR
>   CONSTRUCTING ANYTHING OVER IT Book 004, Number 2116 Jabir said:
>   **Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) forbade that the graves
>   should be plastered or they be used as sitting places (for the
>   people), or a building should be built over them**.
>
> **Abu Musa Al-Ashari enjoined upon us at the time of his death, saying,**
>   “You should hasten with my funeral procession and do not follow me in
>   suspense. Do not put in my grave anything that will come between me
>   and the dust, **and do not build anything over my grave**. Bear witness
>   that I am free of those women who shave their heads, tear their
>   clothes, and strike their faces.” **They said, “Have you heard something
>   about this?” He said, “Yes, from the Messenger of Allah, peace and
>   blessings be upon him. ”** Musnad Ahmad 4/397 no. 19053

Now by these ahadees, it is clear that building shrines over graves is forbidden by the prophet ﷺ, and that sahaba didn't allowed it.

And **the people who are in favor of building shrines over graves, have merely some analogies, or things like that. These ahadees are clear cut and i believe are much stronger than their assumptions and weak references.**

Now, after getting it clear the building on graves. **Let's move to the matter of if we should go there or not.**

So, in this matter, what i hold opinion is that today, in the time when their is every kind of sin being done in shrines, specially shirk of many kinds along with all kind of drugs available and everything. I would rather stay away from such places, because of the fear of getting involved in it. Otherwise visiting graves is allowed and encouraged for men. But as you can read in above ahadees, not to make them place of worshiping, or build some buildings on them.

Lastly, for the people of india, i happen to be from Pakistan, where the situation is more or less same. They go there to ask them for waseela, as them to ask Allah for them, or some people even ask them for their problems. And many believe the person in the grave is listening to them, and will solve their problems, or at-least that they will CONVEY our issues to Allah. Now this is a separate issue. And here is where shirk comes in the scene. And you better ask them, why they believe so. I rather don't believe in this. And i ask Allah directly for whatever my problem is.

Comment: Asking directly from Allah swt is undoubtfully mustahab but why dont people ask shifa or recovery from the disease directly from Allah swt rather ask from the doctor.

Comment: Now this is a long debate about waseela etc, but this question was not about this exactly so i just gave idea why we consider it wrong along with where shirk comes in which was being discussed in comments.